# .NET - Using "Response.BinaryWrite()" makes IE11 close

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer, httpresponse

I have an ASP.NET page and a c# method that takes a memorystream (of an excel-file) and then uses the HTTPResponse-class to stream this file, in binary, to the browser.

```
    public static void WriteStreamToBrowser(MemoryStream streamExcelFile, string filename, bool isResponseEnd = false)
    {
        System.Web.HttpResponse Response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", filename));
        Response.Clear();

        Response.BinaryWrite(streamExcelFile.GetBuffer());
    }
```

Now this method works FINE when I use my asp.net page in Firefox or Chrome. They neatly trigger the websites "do you want to download this file" feature.

However, when using IE11, the browser window instantly closes but the "do you want to download this file?" dialog actually pops up and remains.

I'm guessing that IE needs some special treatment when it comes to the Response-methods but I haven't been able to figure out what I do wrong.

How do I change the above method so that will also work with IE11?

--

Let me know if you need any extra details!

EDIT:

Worth mentioning is that debugging does not throw any exceptions.

Also, the dialoge that pops up is actually the download history.

EDIT 2:

I've tried to follow some advice from other guides and added some stuff. Still, resultat is the same.

```
    public static void WriteStreamToBrowser2(MemoryStream streamExcelFile, string filename, bool isUseNewExcel = true)
    {
        System.Web.HttpResponse Response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        string contentType = isUseNewExcel ? "application/vnd.ms-excel" : "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", filename));
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", streamExcelFile.Length.ToString());
        Response.AddHeader("content-type", contentType);

        Response.BinaryWrite(streamExcelFile.GetBuffer());

        //to avoid ThreadAbortion
        Response.Flush();
        Response.SuppressContent = true;
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        Response.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Not 100% sure, but have you tried adding a `response.end()` after this?

Comment: Yes, it makes no difference.

Comment: You *need* a call to `Response.End()`. Otherwise other content can be written to the file and you'll end up with a corrupted file. By the way ad you able to actually download anything with the "do you want to download this file?" dialog?

Comment: IE cannot detect what method you used to write. How could it? The HTTP protocol does not know about ASP.NET. The problem is *what* you write.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm very new to this.

Comment: This is NOT an IE issue. I was doing just this yesterday with IE11 and it works just fine but I did include Response.Write(). seems like something else is the issue - perhaps your AV software? Did you reset your IE settings completely and remove your temp internet files?

Comment: This is not a "crash" issue.

Comment: I'll change crash to "closes" in the heading

Comment: Ahmed: Could you share the code you used?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I managed to solve the broken excel download by adding a +".xls" to the file name. Why IE but not Chrome and Firefox requires you to explicitly define the extension in the filenamestring, I will never know. To be clear, this did not solve my problem with IE closing my main window but that's not an issue right now.